# HTML list unintentionally cascading

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a menu with hover-over effects created with an unordered list, css, and an image. The menu appears correctly when viewed in IE9, FF v15, and Chome v22. However, the menu does not appear correctly in compatibility mode in IE9, or when setting Document Mode to IE8 standards or below. It has some cascarding effect where the list elements each appear slightly lower than the last.

The correct appearance is:
[image]

The appearance in compatibility mode or Document Mode IE8 or below is:
[image]

The HTML is:

```
<div class="Menu2">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php" class="MenuHome">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="coolRooms.php" class="MenuCoolRooms">CoolRooms</a></li>
            <li><a href="onlineBooking.php" class="MenuOnlineBookings">OnlineBookings</a></li>
            <li><a href="termsAndConditions.php" class="MenuTermsAndConditions">Terms&Conditions</a></li>
            <li><a href="madigansMilk.php" class="MenuMadigansMilk">Madigan'sMilk</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
```

The CSS is:

```
.Menu2 {
    z-index:100px;
}
.Menu2 ul {
    width:850px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    /*margin-left:98px;*/
    list-style-type:none;
}
.Menu2 li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height:65px;
    background-image: url(../images/Menu.png);
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
.MenuHome {
    width:99px;
    background-position:0 0;
}
.MenuCoolRooms {
    width:149px;
    background-position:-99px 0;
}
.MenuOnlineBookings {
    width:195px;
    background-position:-249px 0;
}
.MenuTermsAndConditions {
    width:221px;
    background-position:-444px 0;
}
.MenuMadigansMilk {
    width:186px;
    background-position:-665px 0;
}
.MenuHome:hover {
    background-position:0 -65px;
}
.MenuCoolRooms:hover {
    background-position:-99px -65px;
}
.MenuOnlineBookings:hover {
    background-position:-249px -65px;
}
.MenuTermsAndConditions:hover {
    background-position:-444px -65px;
}
.MenuMadigansMilk:hover {
    background-position:-665px -65px;
}
```

The raw menu image is:
[image]

The left and right edges of the menu (that exist above the blue background) can be ignored for the sake of this question.

Any ideas how to correct the flow of the list elements so they remain horizontally aligned in the other IE versions/modes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/9-most-common-ie-bugs-and-how-to-fix-them/
2. Staircase Effect

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Adding .Menu2 ul li { float:left; } was all I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [modernizer](http://modernizr.com/)js plugin for fixing css and html for older browsers

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll keep that in mind if I hit any related issues in future. See my comment under Derik's answer for the fix I needed.

Comment: If you are building a site for public use with people with lot of different browser you can consider to use one of all boilerplates check out [html5boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) or the [initializr](http://www.initializr.com/)